# Как запретить pjax yii2 менять url после js запроса?

Tags: yii2, pjax

Борюсь уже какой день.

есть вид с pjax

```
<?php 
Pjax::begin([
    'id' => 'form_pjax',
    'clientOptions' => ['method' => 'POST'],
    'enablePushState' => false
]);
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'edit-form',
    'options' => [
        'method' => 'post',
        'data-pjax' => true
    ]]);
    /* ................................. */
    ActiveForm::end();
Pjax::end(); 
?>
```

и есть js запрос

```
var form = $('form#edit-form');

var formData = form.serialize();
$.pjax.reload({
    container:'#form_pjax', 
    url:form.attr('action'), 
    method:'post', 
    data:formData, 
    push: false, 
    timeout: 2000
});
```

И там и там указал push:false, но все равно при выполнении запроса меняется адресная строка.... Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте ещё добавить

```
'enableReplaceState' => false
```

Comment: К сожалению не сработало ((

Comment: я вот не уверен... если какие-то параметры в js передаются и рулится reload именно через js, наверное тогда туда надо прописать `replace    : false,` ..... потому что пыховская настройка влияет только если не программно вызывается reload (типа кликом на ссылку)